# Python SHA-256 throws a TypeError

Tags: python, hash, sha256

I'm trying to make a simple program that generates 10 numbers through `random`. Then, it passes them to `hashlib`, which SHA-256 those random numbers. Finally, the hashes are shown to the user.

This is my Code:

```
import random
import hashlib

number1 = random.randint(0, 999999999999)
number2 = random.randint(0, 999999999999)
number3 = random.randint(0, 999999999999)
number4 = random.randint(0, 999999999999)
number5 = random.randint(0, 999999999999)
number6 = random.randint(0, 999999999999)
number7 = random.randint(0, 999999999999)
number8 = random.randint(0, 999999999999)
number9 = random.randint(0, 999999999999)
number10 = random.randint(0, 999999999999)

result1 = hashlib.sha256(number1)
result2 = hashlib.sha256(number2)
result3 = hashlib.sha256(number3)
result4 = hashlib.sha256(number4)
result5 = hashlib.sha256(number5)
result6 = hashlib.sha256(number6)
result7 = hashlib.sha256(number7)
result8 = hashlib.sha256(number8)
result9 = hashlib.sha256(number9)
result10 = hashlib.sha256(number10)

print("Hash 1:", result1)
print("Hash 2:", result2)
print("Hash 3:", result3)
print("Hash 4:", result4)
print("Hash 5:", result5)
print("Hash 6:", result6)
print("Hash 7:", result7)
print("Hash 8:", result8)
print("Hash 9:", result9)
print("Hash 10:", result10)
```

PyCharm says it's fine. However, when you run it, it throws this error:

```
C:\Users\WINDOWS\Documents\PyToC\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/WINDOWS/Documents/PyToC/build/aquamine.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/WINDOWS/Documents/PyToC/build/aquamine.py", line 15, in <module>
    result1 = hashlib.sha256(number1)
TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why does this happen? Is there any way I can fix it.

Comment: You need a bytes like object as argument for that, not a number: https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html

Comment: How do I covert the number to bytes? encode() doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `bytes(str(num), 'utf-8')` probably?

Answer (score 2):

This is because integer does not support Buffer API (https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html) you can convert it to bytes which would support this.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes

```
result1 = hashlib.sha256(number1.to_bytes((number1.bit_length() + 7) // 8, byteorder='big'))
```

byteorder can be 'big' or 'little' depending the where the most significant bit is

Answer (score 0):

it's because it `sha256()` wants **bytes** not numbers nor strings.. so here you can do

```
result1 = hashlib.sha256(str(number1).encode())
# also for result2, result3, ...
```